# backbone.js this.model is undefined wine application example

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm learning backbone js for the first time and trying to get the example wine app working, it's pulling in from the db fine and the list view displays a list of users but when it calls WineDetails it's throwing an error.

here's the code:

```
// Models
window.Wine = Backbone.Model.extend();

window.WineCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model:Wine,
  url:"../api/users"
});


// Views
window.WineListView = Backbone.View.extend({

  tagName:'ul',

  initialize:function () {
    this.model.bind("reset", this.render, this);
  },

  render:function (eventName) {
    _.each(this.model.models, function (wine) {
        $(this.el).append(new WineListItemView({model:wine}).render().el);
    }, this);
    return this;
  }

});

window.WineListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

  tagName:"li",

  template:_.template($('#tpl-user-list-item').html()),

  render:function (eventName) {
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  }

});

window.WineView = Backbone.View.extend({

  template:_.template($('#tpl-user-details').html()),

  render:function (eventName) {
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  }

});


// Router
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes:{
    "":"list",
    "users/:id":"wineDetails"
  },

  initialize:function () {
    this.wineList = new WineCollection();
    this.wineListView = new WineListView({model:this.wineList});

  },

  list:function () {
    this.wineList.fetch();
    $('#sidebar').html(this.wineListView.render().el);
  },

  wineDetails:function (id) {
    this.wine = this.wineList.get(id);
    this.wineView = new WineView({model:this.wine});
    $('#content').html(this.wineView.render().el);
  }
});

var app = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

and the html

```
<div id="header"><span class="title">Backbone Cellar</span></div>

<div id="sidebar"></div>

<div id="content">
  <h2>Welcome to Backbone Cellar</h2>
  <p>
  This is a sample application part of of three-part tutorial showing how to build a CRUD    application with Backbone.js.
  </p>
</div>

<!-- Templates -->
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-user-list-item">
  <a href='#users/<%= user_id %>'><%= user_id %></a>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="tpl-user-details">
<div class="form-left-col">

  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="<%= user_id %>" required/>

</div>

</script>

</div>
```

and the error in firebug

```
TypeError: this.model is undefined
$(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
```

I've tried adding _.bindAll(this,"render"); in the initialize function but makes no difference.

Comment: Inspect `this.wine` which is passed as a `model` to the `WineView`. It might be possible that it doesn't have any value. And yes in `WineListView` please rename `model` to `collection`, in the parameter passed in initialization and in the `render` method.

Comment: Your right this.wine is undefined think I need an easier CRUD example to work with.

Comment: Well, this example is also not wrong, all what you need to take care is what if the required model isn't there in the collection, you can render content based on that, or may be, you can select an easier example which clears your doubts, what I would say is, try to understand the responsibility and role of every component you write, and what do all the options do, that will help you understand things easily :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your router you only doing wineList.fetch().

You need to handle the success callback like following

```
wineList.fetch({success: function(){
    $("#content").html(new WineListView({model: wineList, page: p}).el);
}});
```

I have sample winecellar project implemented using backbone and requirejs in github.
https://github.com/phillycoder/backbone-require-cellar